# JQuery mobile form, how to process form in a <div role="main" class="ui-content"> w/PHP

Tags: php, jquery, forms, mobile

I have a small three page site where each page is in a div with the data role of "page"
I want the third page to display the results.

Form page div:

```
<div data-role="header">
    <h2>Handle or Knob</h2>

    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#page1" class="ui-btn-active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page2">Test</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->

</div><!-- /header -->



<div role="main" class="ui-content">


    <form method="post" action="#page3">

    <p>I enjoy the twists and turns in life</p>



        <label>
            <input name="radio-choice-0" id="radio-choice-0" type="radio" value="agree">Agree
        </label>
       <label>
            <input name="radio-choice-0" id="radio-choice-1" type="radio" value="disagree">Disagree
        </label>

    <p>Cups are easier to use if they have a handle</p>


        <label>
            <input name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-2" type="radio" value="agree">Agree
        </label>
       <label>
            <input name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-3" type="radio" value="disagree">Disagree
        </label>


        <p>Life pulls me in different directions sometimes</p>



        <label>
            <input name="radio-choice-2" id="radio-choice-4" type="radio" value="agree">Agree
        </label>
       <label>
            <input name="radio-choice-2" id="radio-choice-5" type="radio" value="disagree">Disagree
        </label>

        <a href="#page3"><input type="submit" value="Results">
    </form>

</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

Results page div:

```
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Results</h1>

    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#page1" class="ui-btn-active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page2">Test</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->

</div><!-- /header -->

<div role="main" class="ui-content">

   <?php

        $q1Answer = '';
        $q2Answer = '';
        $q3Answer = '';
        $knobScore = 0;
        $handleScore = 0;

        $knobResult = '';
        $handleResult = '';
        $yourResult = '';



        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            $q1Answer = $_POST['radio-choice-0'];
            $q2Answer = $_POST['radio-choice-1'];
            $q3Answer = $_POST['radio-choice-2'];

            echo $q1Answer;
            echo $q2Answer;
            echo $q3Answer;

        }else{
            echo "Please complete the form";
        }

   ?>


</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

It's a work in progress, right now I'm just trying to get the results to load on the results page. Then I can work out the scoring after.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` is always false because there isn't a field or button with `name="submit"`

Comment: OK, I added name="submit" to the button, but now it triggers the else part of the statement?

Comment: So when the form is posted you get "Please complete the form" ?

Comment: Correct, but it does say that in the right place (#page3)

Comment: You have `<a href="#page3">` before the button which looks like a typo, get rid of that. It's probably intercepting the button click.

Comment: Hmmmm. Without the anchor, pressing the button brings you back to page1.

Answer (score 0):

1.) `action="#page3"` -> If submit should lead back to the same page, just erase the `action` attribute, if it should lead to another page, put the full name of that file including the suffix in there, for example `action="page_3.php"` (but certainly not `action="#page3").

2.) Don't try to verify the submit, but the contents of the inputs:

```
if(isset($_POST['radio-choice-0']) && isset($_POST['radio-choice-1']) and isset($_POST['radio-choice-2'])){
  ....
}
```

Comment: Submit should lead back to the same page, yes, but in the div for page three. That div has a data-role="page"

Comment: I know I'm being obnoxious but technically speaking `action="#page3"` is totally valid and has a purpose, although here there's nothing with `id="page3"`.

Comment: Actually there is

Comment: <div data-role="page" id="page3" data-theme="c">